# Using Sequel, can I create UPDATE statements with a FROM clause

Tags: sql, ruby, sequel

Using [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org) I'd like to create an UPDATE statement like the following (from [Postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html))

```
UPDATE employees SET sales_count = sales_count + 1 FROM accounts
  WHERE accounts.name = 'Acme Corporation'
  AND employees.id = accounts.sales_person;
```

However, looking at the [Sequel documentation](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-update) it's not clear where there's any way to create the FROM clause.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, Ben Lee's answer got me going in the right direction.  Solution:

```
DB[:employees].from(:employees, :accounts).
  where(:accounts__name => 'Acme Corporation').
  update_sql(:employees__sales_count => "employees.sales_count + 1".lit)
```

I'm a bit uncertain about the use of `.lit` here, but it does seem to do the trick.  (Also, I'm using `update_sql` rather than `update` to produce the SQL output rather than running the command.)

Result, as desired:

```
UPDATE "employees" 
   SET "employees"."sales_count" = employees.sales_count + 1 
  FROM "accounts"
 WHERE ("accounts"."name" = 'Acme Corporation')
```

Answer (score 3):

Everybody else's answers have one tiny superfluous clause.

```
DB.from(:employees, :accounts).
  where(:accounts__name => 'Acme Corporation').
  update_sql(:employees__sales_count => "employees.sales_count + 1".lit)
```

If you're doing a from() with two tables, then the one inside the DB[...] is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use a regular join? It's not exactly your query, but it should accomplish your goals, right?

```
DB[:employees].left_outer_join(:accounts, :sales_person => :id).
    where('accounts.name' => 'Acme Corporation').
    update('employees.sales_count' => 'employees.sales_count' + 1)
```

Comment: Hmm, sounds promising!  This produces the error `Sequel::Error: Need multiple FROM tables if updating/deleting a dataset with JOINs`.  So now I just need to figure out how to add multiple FROMs

Comment: Aha!  yes, this can be done using `DB[:employees].from(:employees, :account)`.  More shortly.